# Python exec in function scope cannot set value

Tags: python, python-3.x, exec

```
import re


value = eval("'Hello「World」'")
c = [
    "g = re.search('.*「(.*)」', value, re.IGNORECASE)",
    "print(value)",
    "value = g.group(1)",
    "print(value)"
]
if c is not None:
    for d in c:
        exec(d)


def test():
    value2 = eval("'Hello「World」'")
    c2 = [
        "g2 = re.search('.*「(.*)」', value2, re.IGNORECASE)",
        "print(value2)",
        "value2 = g2.group(1)",
        "print(value2)"
    ]
    if c2 is not None:
        for d2 in c2:
            exec(d2)

test()
```

Expect result:

```
Hello「World」
World
Hello「World」
World
```

Actual result:

```
Hello「World」
World
Hello「World」
Hello「World」
```

I am running in Python 3.6.2. My question is why cannot exec set the value when it is inside the function?

However, it can set on a new variable.

```
def test2():
    value2 = eval("'Hello「World」'")
    c2 = [
        "g2 = re.search('.*「(.*)」', value2, re.IGNORECASE)",
        "print(value2)",
        "value3 = g2.group(1)",
        "print(value3)"
    ]
    if c2 is not None:
        for d2 in c2:
            exec(d2)

test2()
```

Result:

```
Hello「World」
World
Hello「World」
World
```

How can I make `test()` change `value2` inside `exec`?

Comment: You cannot using `exec` because `exec` always returns `None`, and inside a function, those variables are *local*, and `locals()` cannot be modified dynamically.

Comment: But what are you trying to accomplish here? why do it this way?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Then, how can `exec` read local variable? If it can read, why can't it write? Is there a way to pass current function context to it?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I am writing a web scraper which have site specific code that I load from config file when I execute it.

Comment: Why in the world would you do that? Why don't you make the code a function, and then call the function?

Comment: But read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) particularly, the second note.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Because the config is keep in another projects. Those projects hold the config.

Comment: ... so? Why does that change anything?